# Google webmaster tools API: How to programmatically get a list of backlinks to your site?

Tags: c#, seo, google-search-console

I'd like to get a list of the backlinks reported in Google webmaster tools programaticallly but the GData API doesn't include this.

http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/webmastertools/docs/2.0/reference.html

Is there any good way to get these links?

What's the best way to get a list of backlinks to a site?

Answer (score 0):

the api does not support it.

i use a fake-script (http://fakeapp.com/ a programmable browser) (any programmable browser will do) which gets executed daily the get this specific data. in my opinion it is the best backlinks data you can get.

Answer (score 0):

There is a php script that you can use to download the backlinks as a csv file which you can then use.

https://github.com/Adduc/php-webmaster-tools-downloads

A pull request was just made to the main repo.

Comment: Can you tell me how this works? The docs do not say it can be used for backlinks. Only for: TOP_PAGES
TOP_QUERIES
CRAWL_ERRORS
CONTENT_ERRORS
CONTENT_KEYWORDS
INTERNAL_LINKS
EXTERNAL_LINKS
SOCIAL_ACTIVITY

Comment: Switch to the 'latest-backlinks' branch and it adds LATEST_BACKLINKS